# PyMC3 creating partial Normal distribution

Tags: pymc3

I am using PyMC3 to solve some problems in:
Essentially trying to solve the problem given in Crystal Ball Tutorial.pdf page 3-11. http://faculty.insead.edu/delquie/msp/Other%20downloads/Crystal%20Ball%20Tutorial.pdf

I am trying to create a Normal distribution with mean=8, sd=2 and has a lower limit of 5.

In other words it is a normal distribution (8,2) but instead of -infinity to infinity, it cuts off at 8.

Are there any examples top do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to sample from a bounded (normal) distribution. Using PyMC3 you can set arbitrary bounds on distributions like this.

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    boundedN = pm.Bound(pm.Normal, lower=5.0)
    a = boundedN('a', mu=8, sd=2)
```